# Variables not being Set dynamically in Robotframework

Tags: robotframework

I am using the robotframework for automating testing in one of my project.
I am trying to Set the variable based on the IF condition under *** variables*** section but i see that the whole if condition is getting assigned to it
For example, in one of robot file test.robot

```
*** Variables ***

${Host} =   Set Variable If ${account} == test  testingHost   prodHost
```

I am passing the ${account} value from the command line as

```
robot --variable {account}:test
```

When i try to log the value of ${Host} what i see is the full if condition into it as output. Something like this

```
Started Noisy Test Case ... Set Variable If test==test testingHost
```

Followed the link of builtin(https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Variable%20If) library

Comment: I don't think you can do that in the Variables section. You should do that in Suite Setup or something. A better alternative that saves some code is setting ${Host} in command-line arguments. I used to have a similar code but now I have everything I can in the ROBOT_OPTIONS environment variable.

Comment: You definitely cannot have keyword calls - like `Set Variable If` - inside Variables secrion; it is used exclusively for identifier=value pairs, and anything you put in the value ends up as such (as you saw with the keyword name). If you want conditional logic, you may want to go with initializers in suite setups like Pekka suggested, or - with [python based variables files](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#implementing-variable-file-as-python-or-java-class).